# Ubuntu crashes after removal of Mahjongg and Mines

Tags: uninstall, 17.10, crash

After installing Ubuntu 17.10 I was able to operate it normally.
I then have removed the preinstalled games mahjongg and mines.
With the next restart 17.10 crashed.

Comment: I really don't think the entire OS is reliant on those games...What were your exact steps in removal of those games?

Comment: And what "crash" did you actually experience?